# How to cascade on a column?

Tags: sql-server, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a table that links to another — called `PageTopic` and `TopicPageRole` respectively.

The foreign key on `PageTopic` is:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_PageTopic_TopicPageRole] FOREIGN KEY ([PageRoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicPageRole] ([PageRoleId])
```

Both tables have a column named 'IsMultiMember'; I want to cascade update **if IsMultiMember changes for the PageRoleId** but I've realised that it may lead to unintended consequences — cascading updates if PageRoleId changes.

Have I got it wrong? If I'm right in my thinking, how do I only update the required column when data changes?

Here some code to better explain why I'm trying to do what I am. Some code removed for brevity.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TopicPageRole] (
    [PageRoleId]    TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [MultiMember]   BIT     NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TopicPageRole] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PageRoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_TopicPageRole_PageRoleId_MultiMember] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([PageRoleId] ASC, [MultiMember] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PageTopic] (
    [PageId]      INT      NOT NULL,
    [TopicId]         SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [PageRoleId]  TINYINT  NOT NULL,
    [MultiMember]   BIT      NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PageTopic] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PageId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PageTopic_TopicPageRole] FOREIGN KEY ([PageRoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicPageRole] ([PageRoleId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PageTopic_TopicPageRole2] FOREIGN KEY ([PageRoleId], [MultiMember]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicPageRole] ([PageRoleId], [MultiMember]),

);

// Ensure only one entry per role type where MultiMember is false 

GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PageTopic_PageRoleId_Single]
    ON [dbo].[PageTopic]([TopicId] ASC, [PageRoleId] ASC) WHERE ([MultiMember]='0');
```

`IsMultiMember` is a property of table `PageRole`; in essence it declares whether a topic is allowed to have multiple pages for a particular role. So a hub page can only exist once per topic, while a post can exist multiple times. The `TopicPage` table contains pages along with their assigned topic. Currently, if I don't have a `PageRole`/`IsMultiMember` column also in that table I can't limit the number of pages. I'd be happy to listen to alternative ways.

Comment: Is 'IsMultiMember' really a property of both objects that the tables model? Seems like the design is wrong.

Comment: @MitchWheat I get where you're coming from. This column is there to enforce integrity across several tables.

Comment: Here is a second vote that the challenge you are facing is caused by a design issue.

Comment: @SeanLange - IsMultiMember is a property of table PageRole; in essence it declares whether a topic is allowed to have multiple pages for a particular role. So a hub page can only exist once per topic, while a post can exist multiple times. The TopicPage table contains pages along with their assigned topic. Currently, if I don't have a PageRole/IsMultiMember column also in that table I can't limit the number of pages. I'd be happy to listen to alternative ways.

Comment: If you can share some ddl for those tables I would be happy to take a peek. It doesn't have to be the full and complete table structure but enough to frame the current topic.

Comment: We can't answer this unless we can see your table design, but it does look suspect.

Comment: @SeanLange Added tables.

Comment: @Charlieface Added tables.

Comment: from what i remember cascading cannot be done conditionally. but you can create a trigger that does the job for you if you swing what way

Comment: Given that `PageRoleId` is the primary key for `TopicPageRole` it's not actually likely to change. So I don't see the problem in having a `CASCADE` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see that there would be an issue with using an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on this foreign key. Since `PageRoleId` is the primary key for `TopicPageRole`, it's not actually likely to change ever (it certainly shouldn't be a common occurence). The only cascading would be on `MultiMember`.

However, you should ensure your foreign key is properly indexed if you want the cascading to work efficiently

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PageTopic_PageRoleId_MultiMember]
    ON [dbo].[PageTopic]([TopicId] ASC, [MultiMember] ASC);
```

---

Having said that, you don't need to use the extra column to enforce this constraint. There is another way to do multi-table constraints, using a an indexed view instead of a filtered index.

First, just remove the column and second foreign key from `PageTopic`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PageTopic] (
    [PageId]      INT      NOT NULL,
    [TopicId]         SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [PageRoleId]  TINYINT  NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PageTopic] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PageId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PageTopic_TopicPageRole] FOREIGN KEY ([PageRoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicPageRole] ([PageRoleId]),
    -- make sure you  index the foreign key
    INDEX IX NONCLUSTERED (PageRoleId ASC)
);
```

Now we can create a joined indexed view, and put a unique constraint on it.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW View_PageTopic_PageRoleId_Single
WITH SCHHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
  pt.TopicId,
  pt.PageRoleId
FROM dbo.PageTopic pt
JOIN dbo.TopicPageRole pr ON pr.PageRoleId = pt.PageRoleId
WHERE pr.MultiMember = 0;
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PageTopic_PageRoleId_Single]
    ON dbo.View_PageTopic_PageRoleId_Single([TopicId] ASC, [PageRoleId] ASC);
```

Comment: This seems like quite a clean solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why you need the `IsMultiMember` table, basically, you want to control singularity/plurality of the number of topics on a page and the number of pages where a given topic can be present.

However, your foreign key looks suspect, for three reasons. You have already identified the first reason: `PageTopic.PageRoleId` might change and you may encounter problems when `IsMultiMember` differs between the old and new `PageTopic`. This is a solvable issue, but I would rather use another approach because of the other two problems.

The second problem is that `IsMultiMember` does not really look like a key. Yes, in theory you can use it as a dimension of a candidate key, but in practice I would advise against it.

The third problem is that you may encounter performance issues when you do bulk updates, bulk deletes or bulk inserts.

So, I would think about the design. The main question is:

**Where does PageTopic.IsMultiMember belong?**

and the answer is: it belongs to the `Page`, not to the `PageTopic`, because it determines whether the page can have multiple topics. Hence, you need to move the `IsMultiMember` field to the `Page` table and the steps would be as follows:

- add an `IsMultiMember` field to your `Page` table
- update your `Page` table, setting its `IsMultiMember` field for every record to the correct value
- drop `IsMultiMember` from `PageTopic` along with the `foreign key` created for it
- create a trigger before insert/update on `PageTopic`, which would check whether the topic had to be unique on the page or the topic has to appear at one page the most and check whether these rules would be violated by the insertion/update, throw an error if so
- create a trigger before update both on `TopicPageRole` and `Page`, so if `IsMultiMember` is to be set to false and there are records in `TopicPageRole` that violate this, then throw an error

Alternatively you can create a stored procedure for these operations and wrap a transaction around them.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. IsMultiMember doesn't determine whether a page can have multiple topics - a page can only have one topic. It actually determines whether a topic can have multiple pages for a specific role/type. For instance, each topic can have many posts, but only 1 hub page.